# Compare attributes of same column in a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns: `TitleID (VARCHAR),Version (BIGINT), CreatedAt (DATETIME)`
Usually different versions of the title come in sequence, however recently I started getting entries where they aren't in sequence, i.e

```
TitleID     Version      CreatedAt
ABCDE         2           2018-06-10 20:28:37
ABCDE         1           2018-06-13 10:00:12
ABCDE         3           2018-06-13 20:00:00
XYZ           2           2018-06-13 20:00:00
XYZ           1           2018-06-13 20:00:01
```

As you can see for Title ABCDE, version 2 came before version 1, version 3 came after version 2 which is expected. For Title XYZ, version 2 came before 1 as well. I'm trying to write a query which will let me know which titles along with their versions which came out of order in the past 2 weeks. For this I tried writing a query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM REVIEWS T1 WHERE T1.TitleID IN
    (SELECT TitleID FROM REVIEWS T2 WHERE CreatedAt > '2018-05-30'
        AND T1.CreatedAt < T2.CreatedAt AND T1.Version > T2.Version)
AND CreatedAt > '2018-05-30';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to itself, omitting the rows where version is equal, then filter for Version/CreatedAt discordance.

```
select 
  t1.TitleID, 
  t1.Version, 
  t1.CreatedAt, 
  t2.Version, 
  t2.CreatedAt 
from reviews t1
join reviews t2 
  on t1.TitleID = t2.TitleID and t1.Version != t2.Version
where 
  (t1.Version > t2.Version and t1.CreatedAt < t2.CreatedAt)
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46377/23)

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense to join. Also is there a way to check t1.CreatedAt is within 1 hour of t2.CreatedAt? i.e to see cases where newer versions came in within 1 hour period of an older version coming in?